# Laravel Eloquent specific columns error

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following in Laravel 4.x using eloquent:

Book table has  a dozen fields.

```
$single_data = Book::
            selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(id as char) SEPARATOR ',') as type_id_list")
            ->first();
```

Question: the data returned is everything within the table inside Book AND type_id_list as seen from the selectRaw.

I would like to ONLY return what I specified within the selectRaw.

It was suggested that you get add an array of columns within first() or get() in order to retrieve this only - however it is not working with custom selectRaw where you specify an expression or your own wording. It throws an error and when the query is analyzed the array that you put in first/get gets appended as part of the select.

Does anyone have a work around?

Comment: Does `first([])` work?

Comment: @Andreas ah, it does work too - but I will use pluck instead as it gives back the value itself immediately and not the object too.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues

Comment: @Andreas you suggested it first - take the credit.

Comment: `first()` and `first([])` gives exactly the same result, which is a `Book` model with single attribute `type_id_list` (and other properties unrelated to the query like `exists` etc) because Eloquent provided with `selectRaw` ignores any previous selects. Given multiple `selectRaw` methods, it will use only last one.

Comment: @deczo it does not. I tested it manually. first() gives me the Book model with all the attributes where as first([]) gave me only the attribute found in the selectRaw

Comment: Not to argue, but... this very code you pasted does this: assign raw expression as a `Builder` column property, then gets the result. Having column prop not null it just ignores what you pass in `first()` or `get()` method. So either your code is more than shown here or it really makes no difference

Comment: @deczo It does not - I have DD selectRaw()->first and it will use the select + book.*. I ran the dump before posting my comments so I can assure you that my finding that I am reporting is correct. that first() and first([]) yields different results

Comment: @azngunit81 You should report it. You know which version you're on, you can answer follow-up questions etc. I can't immediately see what in Laravel would cause this to happen so I won't be making a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first()` will return only that particular column but wrapped in a `Book` object anyway, so use `pluck()` instead:

```
$single_data = Book::
        selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(id as char) SEPARATOR ',') as type_id_list")
          ->pluck('type_id_list');
```

Comment: Note: Andreas' comment first([]) will yield the correct result but I will need to do ->type_id_list to get the info.